# What are the important gifts and graces given to Mary to become Mother of the Church?

Tags: catholicism, biblical-basis, church-history, virgin-mary, church-fathers

Catholic Church Tradition already embraced the view of Mary's role as Mother of the Church.

It says Saint Augustine and Pope Saint Leo the Great both reflected on the Virgin Mary’s importance in the mystery of Christ.

> “In fact the former [St. Augustine] says that Mary is the mother of the members of Christ, because with charity she cooperated in the rebirth of the faithful into the Church, while the latter [St. Leo the Great] says that the birth of the Head is also the birth of the body, thus indicating that Mary is at once Mother of Christ, the Son of God, and mother of the members of his Mystical Body, which is the Church.”

Scripture, the decree says, depicts Mary at the foot of the Cross (cf. Jn 19:25). There she became the Mother of the Church when she “accepted her Son’s testament of love and welcomed all people in the person of the beloved disciple as sons and daughters to be reborn unto life eternal.”
***In 1964, the decree says, Pope Paul VI***

> ***“declared the Blessed Virgin Mary as ‘Mother of the Church,*** that is to say of all Christian people, the faithful as well as the pastors, who call her the most loving Mother’ and established that **‘the Mother of God should be further honoured and invoked by the entire Christian people by this tenderest of titles’ ”**.

In CCC490, Mary's role as Mother of the Saviour required God to endowed Her with important gifts and special graces.

> **490** To become the mother of the Savior, Mary "was enriched by God with gifts appropriate to such a role."132 The angel Gabriel at the moment of the annunciation salutes her as "full of grace".133 In fact, in order for Mary to be able to give the free assent of her faith to the announcement of her vocation, it was necessary that she be wholly borne by God's grace.

> "The most Blessed Virgin Mary was, from the first moment of her conception, by a singular grace and privilege of almighty God and by virtue of the merits of Jesus Christ, Savior of the human race, preserved immune from all stain of original sin.135" (*135 Pius IX, Ineffabilis Deus (1854): DS 2803.*)

**My question is: in Mary's role as Mother of the Church this would entails a much greater gifts & graces because She will now be a Mother of not only of one child, but a Mother to a billion of believers or the redeemed. In human terms it would be impossible**

> "There are an estimated 1.2 billion Roman Catholics in the world, according to Vatican figures. More than 40% of the world's Catholics live in Latin America - but Africa has seen the biggest growth in Catholic congregations in recent years. Mar 14, 2013 - [How many Roman Catholics are there in the world?](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-21443313)

If Mary was Chosen again, too further Her Role as Mother of the Church meaning a Mother to billions of Catholic not withstanding the teaching the Mary is the Mother of all the Redeemed (including other faith").
What kind of gifts & graces from Catholic Teaching and biblical perspective Mary must possessed in order to perform the magnitude of the holy office?

***I am looking for what kind of gifts & graces Mary must possessed in order to  be the Mother of the Church that would attend to the care of each member towards their salvation?***

Catholicism and Church Father teaching will be helpful to appreciate the biblical soundness and realities of this important teaching to give light on the Divine Power of Mary bestowed on Her by the Most High.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/54823/is-mary-omniscient-by-participation-not-by-nature?rq=1). Also, the presentation of the question is not helpful. You abuse of **bold** and _italics_; the quotes are not clearly marked as quotes (using the ">" symbol); and the question is unclear. Please edit to improve formatting and clarify the question.

Comment: @luchonacho thanks for your suggestion.please let me know if my question is already clear to your reading.

Answer (score 1):

Mary is universally acknowledged by the Catholic Church as the Mother of the Church, and this year our beloved Pope Francis officially declared the title a  Feast having calendar it's commemoration the next day (Monday) week after Pentecost Celebration.

*Source*: [Mary, Mother of the Church: A New Celebration](http://www.catholicstand.com/mary-mother-of-the-church-a-new-celebration/)

#### Catechism of the Catholic Church

**Paragraph 6. Mary - Mother of Christ, Mother of the Church**

> **963** Since the Virgin Mary's role in the mystery of Christ and the Spirit has been treated, it is fitting now to consider her place in the mystery of the Church. "The Virgin Mary . . . is acknowledged and honored as being truly the Mother of God and of the redeemer. . . . She is 'clearly the mother of the members of Christ' . . . since she has by her charity joined in bringing about the birth of believers in the Church, who are members of its head."<sup>502</sup> "Mary, Mother of Christ, Mother of the Church."<sup>503</sup>
>
> <sup>502</sup> LG 53; cf. St. Augustine, De virg. 6:PL 40,399.
> <sup>503</sup> Paul VI, Discourse, November 21, 1964.

**. . . she is our Mother in the order of grace**

> **967** By her complete adherence to the Father's will, to his Son's redemptive >work, and to every prompting of the Holy Spirit, the Virgin Mary is the >Church's model of faith and charity. Thus she is a "preeminent and . . . wholly unique member of the Church"; indeed, she is the "exemplary realization"  (*typus*) of the Church.*

> **968** Her role in relation to the Church and to all humanity goes still further. "In a wholly singular way she cooperated by her obedience, faith, hope, and burning charity in the Savior's work of restoring supernatural life to souls. For this reason she is a mother to us in the order of grace." <sup>511</sup>

> **969** "This motherhood of Mary in the order of grace continues uninterruptedly from the consent which she loyally gave at the Annunciation and which she sustained without wavering beneath the cross, until the eternal fulfillment of all the elect. Taken up to heaven she did not lay aside this saving office but by her manifold intercession continues to bring us the gifts of eternal salvation . . . . Therefore the Blessed Virgin is invoked in the Church under the titles of **Advocate, Helper, Benefactress, and Mediatrix.**<sup>512</sup>

The above article of faith & teaching comes from the Catechism of the Catholic Church.

#### Biblical basis

To answer biblically some important passages why Mary is the Mother of the Church Genesis 3:15 provides the starting point. Mary is the Mother of Christ, and Jesus is the 'HEAD OF THE CHURCH". Jesus was born in the most pure womb of Mary.

The Church, the Mystical Body of Christ is born thru Mary's too, How?
Biblically speaking Catholic Church always point to John 19:27 and the Pentecost experienced at the Upper Room.

But since Genesis 3:15 passages point to Mary as the Mother of the Savior.  The succeeding verse gives us the reflections how can Mary become our Mother right after the Fall of Adam & Eve.**Genesis 3:16**

> "To the woman also he said: I will multiply thy sorrows, and thy conceptions: ***in sorrow shalt thou bring forth children,*** and thou shalt be under thy husband's power, and he shall have dominion over thee." (Genesis 3:16)

Now let's  look at the word **"IN SORROW SHALT THOU BRING FORTH CHILDREN"**

Mary by Her fullness of grace, knows the Mission of Christ in the Redemption of Mankind, and in Her **"sea of bitter sorrows"** experienced in Calvary. Mary united the sufferings of Her Immaculate Heart to the Heart of Jesus in redeeming all sinners.

That's why AT THE FOOT OF THE CROSS, the agonizing Jesus seeing that Mary accepted all the redeemed in Her Immaculate Heart said the words "Woman, behold your son". Jesus knew Mary wants to follow further the Will of God not just in Redeeming the sinners but all the way to the Salvation of Souls.

While God prepared a body and preserve the sanctity of Mary's womb a fitting vessel or tabernacle for the Logos/Incarnate.

Mary's Immaculate Heart by Her perfect offering of her Seven Sorrows, Her Immaculate Heart becomes the fitting vessel for the Holy Spirit to dwells fully.

So, in the words of St. Louis De Montfort if the HEAD of the Church comes from the body of the Blessed Virgin Mary the Church the Mystical Body of Christ must come from the same body too.

St. Louis De Montfort states

> " all the elect are in the womb of Mary".

Jesus the Head of the Church was bore in the most pure womb of Mary and all the redeemed was bore by Mary's perfect sorrows in Her Immaculate Heart.

To the question can Mary hear all the prayers of all the Redeemed numbering billions for Catholic alone, the answer can be found in Wisdom 1:7.
Mary merited in Her Sorrowful & Immaculate Heart the fullness of the Holy Spirit dwelling more than Overshadowing.
The Sevenfold gifts of the Holy Spirit empower Mary to hear every utterances of every soul; ***Wisdom 1:7** New American Bible (Revised Edition) (NABRE)*:

> **"For the spirit of the Lord fills the world,
> is all-embracing, and knows whatever is said."**

Mary having a **"glorified body"** as envisioned by St. James the Greater in the year 40AD which is called the **"Pre-Assumption Apparitions",** and the **Sevenfold gifts of the Holy Spirit** this two Great Gifts enables Mary the Mother of the Church to transcends space & time and hear all the utterances of all believers in the power of the Holy Spirit.

These gifts, graces and unique role of the Blessed Virgin Mary is the pending 5th Dogma of the Catholic Church:

> **Mary is the Co-Redemptrix, Mediatrix of all graces and Advocate.**

Comment: The beloved pope Francis said that the idea Mary was the co-redemptrix is foolish. https://cruxnow.com/vatican/2019/12/pope-calls-idea-of-declaring-mary-co-redemptrix-foolishness